# moment.js shows different time for iOS devices than for Android for some reason

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework, momentjs

I struggle since some hours with a problems and don't find any solution. I work with Moment.js in my Ionic Mobile Application.

At some point I get json data with my 'from' and 'to' times in the format of Hours and minutes:

Example business opening times:

{
    "from": 14460000,
    "to": 100740000
}

I use this json data with moment like below:

```
var from_time   = moment(hours.object.from).format("HH:mm");
var to_time     = moment(hours.object.to).format("HH:mm");
```

The problem is that on Android devices everything is correct but on iOS devices the times are converted wrong

Result on Android:
00:01 // 23:59

Result on iOS
01:01 // 00:59

Both phones (android and ios devices) are in the same timezone and same location when I make this test. As well as my Computer (browser console) does show me the correct time (like the Android) only iOS devices are one hour off.

I appreciate any help here...

Comment: I think it would be best if you could be explicit about the time-zone maybe use moment-timezone => https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: I played around with momenttjs.timezone already and tried to change the timezone and also the utc offeset but somehow all did not make any difference. Maybe I used it wrong. If somebody has some example code for me to make it work would be great. I would prefer to fix the timezone for the location for the business anyway. But I was not be able to work it out with my script so far.